Need an accurate way of comparing FLOAT datatypes from two different database architectures
I am doing a data load from MS SQL Server into Aurora PostgreSQL. Many of our tables use the float data type (whether or not this was a wise decision is outside the scope of this post, since the tables in question have been around for over 10 years). I'm having difficulty validating the data since the fractional values change slightly when they are loaded to Postgres, presumably due to the way the different engines store this type (or maybe it's because we're going from X86-64 to ARM). We're not too concerned about exact numbers, but I'd like to get accuracy to three decimal places. Using round(<column>, 3) on both sides has not been fully successful. Any tips on functions I can apply to the columns in each database (doesn't need to be the same) to get the comparisons to be equal?
SQL Server 2019, Postgres 15.4

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149966/comparing-2-float-values-in-sqlserver

Change the datatype to DECIMAL/NUMERIC, if that option exists.
If not, you will have to write your own custom-function which trims the values as per your need (like you have used ROUND(3)).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
